# How to render MP4 using After Effects Script with Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: video, after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

I can add my composition to Adobe Media Encoder Queue using below command

```
app.executeCommand(3800);
```

Now how i can render it from Adobe Media Encoder using render command like this

```
aerender -project /path/to/project/  -comp "Composition"  -v "ERRORS_AND_PROGRESS" -output output.mp4'
```

Thanks

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to start the media encoder render queue from the command line?

Comment: Thanks. Exactly. I want to add my composition to Adobe media encoder render queue and then render it with aerender, all using after effects script

Comment: Why not just use the second command? If you want to render something you don't need media encoder, you can just use aerender.

Comment: Thanks. Stib
actually i want output in MP4 format and AE latest version doesn't support MP4 as an output format so thats why i want to use Media Encoder

Comment: try to install x264 via "mega-codec pack" and choose avi->x264

Comment: Did you ever find a solution on this? I'm having the same issue, and looking for a way to automate rendering of mp4 videos

Comment: No. I rendered video using `Adobe After Effects` default renderer and add an extra step using `FFMPEG` to convert to Mp4

Answer (score 1):

Better later than never.

Since After Effects CC 2015.3 (13.8) you can send your comp to AME queue and render it immédiate with the recently used template.

app.project.renderQueue.canQueueInAME --> false is there is nothing to render in AE
app.project.renderQueue.queueInAME(false); --> false = no render, true = render immedialty in AME

Adobe exemple :

```
// Scripting support for Queue in AME.
// Requires Adobe Media Encoder 11.0.
{
    if (app.project.renderQueue.canQueueInAME == true)
    {
        // Send queued items to AME, but do not start rendering.
        app.project.renderQueue.queueInAME(false);
    }
    else {
        alert("There are no queued item in the Render Queue.");
    }
}
```

My exemple of use :

```
var resultFile = new File(outputVideoPath + outputVideoName)
var renderQueue = app.project.renderQueue;
var render = renderQueue.items.add(comp);
render.outputModules[1].file = resultFile;

app.project.renderQueue.queueInAME(true);
```

More details : https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2230567